# Liquid Template Linter

Tags: front-end

Has anyone here had a good experience linting/doing code quality checking for liquid files within Shopify?

I'm having a hard time trying to find a linter that will validate the liquid code in my HTML without throwing an error.

If anyone knows of a cli tool/service/program that does this
Or a list of different services you used to do this.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one OS linter called [Liquid-linter](https://github.com/tomheller/liquid-linter) but it is not actively developed anymore.

> A node package that lets you lint liquid template strings.

Comment: Sorry I am looking for something thats hopefully been developed recently or a service

Comment: I ended up using this package internally after modifying it to work, liquid-node -> liquid, you can see my implementation here: https://github.com/cgilbe27/liquid-linter

Answer (score 1):

Liquid includes this functionality by default,

> Liquid also comes with a stricter parser that can be used when editing templates to give better error messages when templates are invalid.

Source: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid#error-modes

*Update*

> Liquid is an open-source template language created by Shopify and written in Ruby.

Source: https://shopify.github.io/liquid

Comment: Theres no way to set the stricter parser for Shopify

Comment: Also, the link is for Ruby on Rails

Comment: That's because Shopify wrote liquid in Ruby. This is the original implementation.

Comment: Unfortunately the original implementation doesnt allow me to lint the language